# AES decryption in java padding error

Tags: java, cryptography, aes

I have an assignment to decrypt AES using Java but I keep getting a pad block corrupted error. I know this problem has been addressed in multiple threads everywhere but I still can't figure it out.

I have this information given to me:

key : 0123456789abcdef

IV: 0000000000000000

encrypted string: 1ff4ec7cef0e00d81b2d55a4bfdad4ba

which should give the string "Plain text" according to the assignment.

This is my code: (IVtest array is the same as KeyIvEncrypted but with hex instead)

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.BufferedBlockCipher;

import java.util.Base64;



public class AESdecryptor {
/*
    private static String[] KeyIvEncrypted = new String[]{
            "ABEiM0RVZneImaq7zN3u/w==",
            "AAECAwQFBgcICQoLDA0ODw==",
            "ZtrkahwcMzTu7e/WuJ3AZmF09DE="
            };*/
    public static String[] KeyIvEncrypted = new String[]{
            new String("0123456789abcdef"),
            new String("0000000000000000"),
            new String("1ff4ec7cef0e00d81b2d55a4bfdad4ba")
            };
    public static byte[][] Ivtest = {{0x0,0x1,0x2,0x3,0x4,0x5,0x6,0x7,0x8,0x9,0xa,0xb,0xc,0xd,0xe,0xf},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0x1,0xf,0xf,0x4,0xe,0xc,0x7,0xc,0xe,0xf,0x0,0xe,0x0,0x0,0xd,0x8,0x1,0xb,0x2,0xd,0x5,0x5,0xa,0x4,0xb,0xf,0xd,0xa,0xd,0x4,0xb,0xa}};

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, UnsupportedEncodingException, InvalidKeySpecException{
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        System.out.println(new String(decrypt(),"ISO-8859-1"));



    }

    private static byte[] transform(int mode, byte[] keyBytes, byte[] ivBytes, byte[] messageBytes) throws InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeySpecException
    {
        final SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        final IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/pkcs7Padding");
        cipher.init(mode, keySpec, ivSpec);
        return cipher.doFinal(messageBytes);
    }

    public static byte[] decrypt() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, UnsupportedEncodingException, InvalidKeySpecException{
         //return AESdecryptor.transform(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, Base64.getDecoder().decode(KeyIvEncrypted[0]), Base64.getDecoder().decode(KeyIvEncrypted[1]), Base64.getDecoder().decode(KeyIvEncrypted[2]));
         return AESdecryptor.transform(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, Ivtest[0], Ivtest[1], Ivtest[2]);

    }
}
```

Comment: Your input strings are hex but you never decode them to `byte[]`.

Comment: @Robert, KeyIvEncrypted is never used there.
Author, that's why Maarten Bodewes asked you to clean up your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I needed some time to reset my mind and I needed a puzzle. You are the lucky one.

The following code will solve your issue, I'll put the remarks below...

```
package so;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex;

public class AESdecryptor {
    public static String[] KeyIvEncrypted = new String[]{
            new String("0123456789abcdef"),
            new String("0000000000000000"),
            new String("1ff4ec7cef0e00d81b2d55a4bfdad4ba")
            };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        // Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        byte[] decrypted = decrypt();
        System.out.println(new String(decrypted, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
    }

    private static byte[] transform(int mode, byte[] keyBytes, byte[] ivBytes, byte[] messageBytes)
            throws GeneralSecurityException {
        final SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        final IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(mode, keySpec, ivSpec);
        return cipher.doFinal(messageBytes);
    }

    public static byte[] decrypt() throws GeneralSecurityException {
         return AESdecryptor.transform(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, KeyIvEncrypted[0].getBytes(), KeyIvEncrypted[1].getBytes(), Hex.decode(KeyIvEncrypted[2]));
    }
}
```

The following issues were found:

- the key and IV are specified in (ASCII) text. Keys and IV's should not be encoded as text, as each byte should be equally possible;
- the IV should not be static, but indistinguishable from random;
- the IV is not a "zero" IV, as that would consist of bytes set to 0x00, not bytes set to the character '0', i.e. 0x30;
- Bouncy Castle is not needed, [PKCS#5 is identical to PKCS#7](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9043/1172) when it comes to padding;
- the ciphertext is encoded in hexadecimals, so you need to decode them using two hex digits grouped together to make one byte (I've used the `Hex` class from Bouncy as you already have that it seems).

And please note that encryption doesn't equal security *even if* performed correctly.

Comment: Yes, it works thank you so much! I actually tried to solve this identically as your solution before hehe but I did not know you had to decode them using the Hex class.

Awesome!

Comment: Don't forget to hit the accept-V mark on the left of the answer if this (or any other answer) best answers your question. It's the best way of saying thanks on SO (and upvoting of course, when that's available to you).